# Listening for Change at Entry Save

Tags: plugin-development, entries, events

I want to send an email if/when an entry is saved with a lightswitch switched on after previously being off.

I have the below code in my plugin's init file, but I don't know how to

1. check for the section uid and verify that it's the right section or
2. check the previous value and compare it to the value being saved.

```
    Craft::$app->elements->on(Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(ElementEvent $e) {
            $element = $e->element;
            
            
    
        });
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for this instead.

```
Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Element::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
    static function (ModelEvent $event) {
        $entry = $event->sender;
        if ($entry->status === 'disabled'
            && $entry->propagating
            && $entry->resaving
            && ElementHelper::isDraftOrRevision($entry)) {
            return; // do nothing if disabled/draft/resaving...
        }
        if ($entry->section->handle === 'my-handle') { // check section handle
            // call your preferred msg client: slack, email, mailgun...
        }
    }
);
```